# Calendar.getTimeInMillis() keep cauing app to crash

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, alarmmanager

i have been trying to create an alarm that fire every 8:30 in the morning but my app keep crashing
and logcat keep showing me this error
**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()' on a null object reference**

i even check android doc their code is the same. please help

```
class MotivationViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) { 

private var alarmManager: AlarmManager? = null
    private var notifyPendingIntent: PendingIntent


init {
     
        alarmManager = application.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        notifyPendingIntent = Intent(application, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(application, 0, intent, 0)
        }

//start alarm
        startAlarm()

    }


    // Set the alarm to start at approximately 8:30 p.m.
    private val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, 44)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    }


    val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1_000L * 10



    private fun startAlarm() {
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager?.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                calendar.timeInMillis,
                notifyPendingIntent
            )
        }

    }
}
```

this my full viewModel code

Comment: This means that your calendar is null. Maybe your "private val calendar" is not visible in startAlarm()?

Comment: i am using it in ViewModel can that cause it

Comment: Maybe share a little bit more code than this, since I don't know what is what in here.

Comment: Try moving private val calendar and val trigger time above init. I am not sure how this works in Kotlin but you are using the method startAlarm() inside your init. Maybe init is called before these two are created.

Comment: ohh thanks ill try that

Comment: wow thank!! can't thank you enough i have been stuck with it since morning, never thought of moving it above Init.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

just a little correction with the help of **SlothCoding**

i just move the calendar about init block.